# PHP OOP Architectural Issue

Tags: php, oop, architecture

This question may be obvious to some, but I am just beginning to scratch the surface of multi-tier architecture with web applications, particularly with PHP. I have a library containing several objects and it is expanding quickly.  I always try to think in terms of re-useability and break my projects down into small, reusable, and loosely coupled components so that I am not only creating the project but I am also creating the parts for future projects.  I am trying to design a sort of package management system so that I can stop using the absolute paths within include statements for objects.  I would like to have a single file containing includes to every class file within my library.  Along with the includes, I want to add a class with a "singleton" pattern that will allow me to grab instances of every object that I have in the library on demand.  I plan to create a static getter for each object that returns a reference to a new instance.  Basically, something like this...

```
include('classa.php');
include('classb.php');
include('classc.php');
class pacman{
     private static $instance_stack;
     public static function GetPackage($strPackage){
         if(!self::$instance_stack){
             self::$instance_stack['classa']=new ClassA();
             self::$instance_stack['classb']=new ClassB();
             self::$instance_stack['classc']=new ClassC();
         }
         if(array_key_exists(strtolower($strPackage),self::$instance_stack)){
             return self::$instance_stack[strtolower($strPackage)];
         }
         else{
             return false;
         }
     }

}
```

Then if I want to get class a...

```
include('pacman.php');
$ClassA = pacman::GetPackage('classa');
```

I realize that this is a very rudimentary implementation.  My example just covers the bare minimum.  My problem isn't implementing this; rather, it is a question of whether or not hundreds of uninstantiated classes from the includes will have a noticeable effect on performance.  If so, does anyone know of a workaround?  I can't tell you how hard it is to keep track of the relative paths of hundreds of classes all sorted into directors by content.

Comment: [In Yoda voice] Before you can reuse, you must first use. Preoccupation with needs of future projects oft to failure of present project leads.

Comment: There is no preoccupation.  Why would I take 2 hours to creAte a project specific component when I could take 2:30 and creat a generic and reusable component.  Long term and short, it makes more sense.  I'd rather have a single generic function being used in 500 places with polymorphism than 500 variations scattered through the code base.  You want to talk about a nightmare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try autoloading them:

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}

$obj  = new ClassA();
$obj2 = new ClassB(); 
?>
```

This loads classes "on-demand", reducing the overhead and need to have all files included up-front. More information here: http://php.net/autoload

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your performance question is - it doesn't matter. Until you have a Facebook2, Yahoo2 or Googl2 you won't notice any difference.

I would personally discourage you from extensive use of singletones. It's a GLOBAL with a nice name. Makes your code difficult to work with in a long term.

If you are interested in reusable packages / library learn about [Phar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php).

If you need a static getter everywhere check the latest 5.4.x feature called [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). It will help you avoid code repetition.

Finally, don't use require for your classes. Use [autoload](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php).

Comment: Kudos for the help.  With autoloading, are the classes available in the global scope?